# Strange Behaviour moving from firebird sql version 2.5 to version 4

Tags: c#, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

I have a Windows application written in C# using embedded firebird sql version 2.5.5.26952, which I am re-working it to update to embedded firebird sql version 4.0.0.2496. I have update the fdb file to the new version,and all the tables and sprocs, are there. When run a cmd.Fill() command for a selected statement rows are returned, if I do a update for a row in the table, I get the expected results back fine. but If I do a insert nothing is returned, and no errors are thrown, but the data is added to the database. If I run the sproc from the FireRobin application, the data is inserted, and a row is returned, so I'm at a loss to know why it is not working from my C# application. below is slimmed down version of the code.

The 2.5 version is using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.4.10.0.0

The 4.0 version is using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.9.0.2

```
using (var cmd = new FbDataAdapter("PROC_UPSERTPEOPLE", _connection)
{
  DataTable data = new DataTable();

  cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("SURNAME", FbDbType.Text).Value = item.Surname;
  cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("FORENAMENAME", FbDbType.Text).Value = item.Forename);

  var transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
  cmd.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.SelectCommand.Transaction = transaction;
  var result = cmd.Fill(data);
  transaction.Commit();
}
```

On a update result contains 1, and data has the expected result, but on a insert result = 0, and data has no rows in.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the simple version fo the sproc in question

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE PROC_UPSERTPEOPLE_SLIM
(
  RECID     INTEGER,
  SURNAME   VARCHAR(100),
  FORENAME  VARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS
(
  ID        INTEGER,
  LSURNAME  VARCHAR(100),
  LFORENAME VARCHAR(100)
)
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE local_id integer;
DECLARE VARIABLE local_surname varchar(100);
DECLARE VARIABLE local_forename varchar(100);
BEGIN

  select
    ID,
    FORENAME,
    SURNAME
  FROM
    APA_PEOPLE
  WHERE
    (:RECID IS NOT NULL AND ID = :RECID)
    OR (:RECID IS NULL
      AND FORENAME = :FORENAME
      AND SURNAME = :SURNAME)
  INTO
    :local_id,
    :local_forename,
    :local_surname;

  IF (:local_id IS NULL) then
  begin
    UPDATE OR INSERT INTO APA_PEOPLE(FORENAME, SURNAME)
    VALUES(:FORENAME, :SURNAME)
    MATCHING (FORENAME, SURNAME);
  end
  else
  begin
    UPDATE APA_PEOPLE SET FORENAME = :FORENAME,
      SURNAME = :SURNAME
    WHERE ID = :local_id;
  end

  FOR
    SELECT
      ID,
      SURNAME,
      FORENAME
    from
      APA_PEOPLE
    WHERE
      (:RECID IS NOT NULL AND ID = :RECID)
      OR (:RECID IS NULL
        AND FORENAME = :FORENAME
        AND SURNAME = :SURNAME)
    INTO
      :ID,
      :LSURNAME,
      :LFORENAME
  DO
  begin
    suspend;
  end

END;
```

**Update**

To answer my own question, being mainly a TSQL developer, DSQL seems strange, change the sproc to the following, which is simpler

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE PROC_UPSERTPEOPLE_SLIM (
    RECID integer,
    SURNAME varchar(100),
    FORENAME varchar(100)
)
RETURNS (ID integer)SQL SECURITY INVOKER

AS
BEGIN

  UPDATE OR INSERT INTO APA_PEOPLE(FORENAME, SURNAME)
  VALUES(:FORENAME, :SURNAME)
  MATCHING (FORENAME, SURNAME)
  RETURNING ID INTO :ID;

END;
```

but also had to change the way it was called, to use

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE PROC_UPSERTPEOPLE_SLIM(@RECID, @SURNAME, @FORENAME)
```

This does seem counter intuitive, I had assumed a stored procedure was a stored procedure, and there are not two different flavors. Oh well it works now, so move on to getting the rest of the app to work.

Comment: What is the code of `PROC_UPSERTPEOPLE`? Also, have you considered trying to modify one thing at a time, to isolate whether the problem is Firebird 2.5 -> 4.0 or FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient 4.10.0.0 -> 9.0.2?

Comment: try a regular `insert into .... returning ...` command. API-wise such a query is also classified  as "sp call" kind, whic h allows it to returnb 1D vector of parameters back to application.  So, would this work both in your old library and server and in new ones?  Also, try running both applications in stand-alone server not embedded. Doing so you would be able to pick into information flow using TraceAPI (i'd suggest http://fbProfiler.sf.net for it but IBExpert can suffice too, albeit with less funcitonal GUI). P.S. shouldn't query params be @-prefixed as in https://firebirdfaq.org/faq348/ ?

Comment: I've add a simple version of the sprocs code, to the issue, am going to try a regular insert state see wheat that gives me.

Comment: I've tried SELECT * FROM PROC_UPSERTPEOPLE(params), with the same result, data is being inserted into the database but no data is being returned.